# (android) I want to my layout available for large screens too

Tags: android, xml, layout, margin

I want to my layout available for large screens too.On large screens background image grow up but my buttons remains on the left. I try to set margin but it does not work .
My button xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ex"
    android:layout_width="149dp"
    android:layout_height="183dp"
    android:layout_x="165dp" 
    android:layout_y="262dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

what can ı do

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Read this, it should give you some ideas about how to deal with screen sizes: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I want to my layout support large screeens,normal screens,small screens but it

Comment: but it in large screens my buttons dont look same to normal screen

Comment: because you are giving the fix width and height to you button.which remains fix in small and in large screen also

Comment: true but what can ı do? if ı dont give fix size what can ı do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parent View other than `AbsoluteLayout`, remove `Layout_x` & `Layout_y` and set the Gravity of the parent View to Center

Comment: if ı dont give fix size what can ı do .. i must be use linear layout and match_parent or wrap_content

Comment: Layout_x & Layout_y are related to location of the View, not its size. Set the size to be fixed (if the size is not your problem) and use a parent Linear layout with gravity set to center.

Answer (score 1):

dude check [Supporting different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). do some google on writing layouts for different screen sizes you will get plenty of help.

Comment: if ı dont give fix size what can ı do .. i must be use linear layout and match_parent or wrap_content